# cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 300013 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: laravel-8

I am trying to make payment using omnipay paypal but I get

cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 300013 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

could any one help and this is my code

## OmnipayService.php:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Services;

use Omnipay\Omnipay;

class OmnipayService{ 
 

    protected $gateway = ''; 

     
    public function __construct( $payment_method = 'PayPal_Express' )
    {
        
        if( is_null($payment_method) || $payment_method == 'PayPal_Express'){
            
            $this->gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');

            // $this->gateway->setClientId(env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID'));
            // $this->gateway->setSecret(env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET'));

             $this->gateway->setUsername(config('services.paypal.username'));
             $this->gateway->setPassword(config('services.paypal.password'));
             $this->gateway->setSignature(config('services.paypal.signature'));
            $this->gateway->setTestMode(config('services.paypal.sandbox'));
        } 

        
        return $this->gateway;

    }

    public function purchase(array $parameter){
        
            $response = $this->gateway->purchase($parameter)->send();
            return $response;

    }

    public function refund(array $parameter){

        $response = $this->gateway->refund($parameter)->send();
        return $response;

    }

    public function complete(array $parameter){

        $response = $this->gateway->completePurchase($parameter)->send();
        return $response;

    }

    public function getCancelUrl($order_id){
        
        return route('checkout.cancel' , $order_id);
    }

    public function getReturnUrl($order_id){
        
        return route('checkout.complete' , $order_id);
    }

    public function getNotifyUrl($order_id){
        
        $env = config('services.paypal.sandbox') ? 'sandbox' : 'live';
        return route('checkout.webhook.ipn' , [$order_id, $env]);
    }

    

}
```

## PaymentController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\OrderTransaction;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\ProductCoupon;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\Frontend\Customer\OrderCreatedNotification;
use App\Services\OmnipayService;
use App\Services\OrderService;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Omnipay\Omnipay;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

    public function checkout(){
        return view('frontend.checkout');
    } 
 
    
    public function checkout_now(Request $request){ 

       
        $order = (new OrderService)->createOrder($request->except(['_token','submit']));
        
        
            $omniPay = new OmnipayService('PayPal_Express');
            
            $response = $omniPay->purchase([
                'amount' => $order->total,
                'transactionId' => $order->id,
                'currency'  => $order->currency,
                'returnUrl' => $omniPay->getReturnUrl($order->id),
                'cancelUrl' =>  $omniPay->getCancelUrl($order->id),
                
            ]);

    
            if( $response->isRedirect() ){
                $response->redirect();
            }else{
                return $response->getMessage();
            }

            toast($response->getMessage() , 'error'); //using realrashed sweet alert lab

            return redirect()->route('frontend.index');

    }
 

    public function cancelled($order_id){
        $order = Order::find($order_id);
        $order->update([
            'order_status' => Order::CANCELED
        ]);

        $order->products()->each(function ($order_product){
            $product = Product::whereId($order_product->pivot->product_id)->first();
            $product->update([
                'quantity' => $product->quantity + $order_product->quantity
            ]);
            
        });

        toast('You have cancelled your order payment!' , 'error'); //using realrashed sweet alert lab

        return redirect()->route('frontend.index');

    }

    public function completed($order_id){
        

        $order = Order::find($order_id);

        $omniPay = new OmnipayService('PayPal_Express');

        $response = $omniPay->complete([
            'amount'        => $order->total, 
            'transactionId' => $order->id,
            'currency'      => $order->currency,
            'returnUrl'     => $omniPay->getReturnUrl($order->id),
            'cancelUrl'     => $omniPay->getCancelUrl($order->id),
            'notifyUrl'     => $omniPay->getNotifyUrl($order->id),
        ]);

        if( $response->isSuccessful() ){
            $order->update(['order_status' => Order::PAYMENT_COMPLETED]);
            $order->transactions()->create([
                    'transaction' => OrderTransaction::PAYMENT_COMPLETED,
                    'transaction_number' => $response->getTransactionReference(),
                    'payment_result' => 'success'
            ]);

            if( session()->has('coupon') ){
                $coupon = ProductCoupon::whereCode( session()->get('coupon')['code'] )->first();
                $coupon->increment('used_times'); // means add 1 to used_times field in database
    
            }

            Cart::instance('default')->destroy();

            session()->forget([
                'coupon',
                'saved_customer_address_id',
                'saved_shipping_company_id',
                'saved_payment_method_id',
                'shipping',
            ]);

            // send notificatin to user how are admin or upervisor
            User::whereHas('roles',function ($query){
                $query->whereIn('name' , ['admin','supervisor']);
            })->each(function ($admin , $key) use ($order){
                $admin->notify(new OrderCreatedNotification($order));
            });

            

            toast('Your recent payment is successful with reference code: ' . $response->getTransactionReference() , 'success');
            return redirect()->route('frontend.index');
        }

    }  

    public function webhook($order , $env){
        //
    } 
}
```

I tried to download OpenSSl and tried set_time_out(0) and so many solution but no result yet ..